# React native - process the current camera image without triggering the shutter

Tags: reactjs, android-camera, react-native, react-native-ios

is it possible to process the current camera image without the user triggering the shutter using react native?

Thank you!

Comment: curious to know the use case.

Comment: I want to implement some very simple CV approaches which can be done in js

Comment: Hey @khuesmann, got a solution for this?

Comment: @WiliamBrochensquejunior No, unfortunately not